# Why Escape key on keyup display textbox value again

Tags: javascript, textbox, onkeyup

I have very simple JavaScript function which clear textbox on Escape key press.

```
    $("#txtTerm").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27 ) {
            $("#txtTerm").val('');
            } 
    });
```

It actually working perfectly,

**Problem:** When I press again Escape key, I got old textBox value in textbox, and when I release Escape key, Value in textbox clear again,

> **Scenario**  :  In a textbox enter some value let say : "INDIA".
>   Now, I press ESCAPE,  Textbox becomes empty " " ;
>
> Now textbox is empty.
>
> Again if I start pressing ESCAPE ( when textbox is empty) , for that moment I got "INDIA" visible in textbox
>   And after release ESCAPE key, Textbox again clear.

Is there any solution possible , or sounds like a bug or some security issue?

**UPDATE :**

Somehow its not reproduced in fiddle,
but here is the link which shows some other people also facing same issue.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=524360

Comment: Please fiddle your code.

Comment: your code is ok. what browser you are using?

Comment: Tested on latest version of Chrome and FireFox @ kp ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#txtTerm").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27 ) {
            $("#txtTerm").val(' ');
            $("#txtTerm").blur() // Loose focus on input field
            } 
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/943/)

Comment: Thank you @shridhar, but again if I want to write something in textbox then I have to click/or use tab  on textbox. otherwise because of blur function I can not write again.